# Using TextFormatter Property

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

How can I use the textFormatter property to capitalize words that are typed into a textfield?

```
override val root = vbox {
    textfield(model.instrument) {
        textFormatter = TextFormatter (change -> change.text.toUpperCase() )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TornadoFX actually has a filter builder that incorporates a text formatter:

```
override val root = vbox {
    textfield(model.instrument) { 
        filterInput { change ->
            change.text = change.text.toUpperCase()
            true
        }
    }
}
```

The builder needs a boolean to determine if the new input is valid or not so it can actually accept or reject input.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple:

```
                textFormatter = TextFormatter<String> { change ->
                    change.text = change.text.toUpperCase()
                    change
                }
```